# Replace parameters that can be changed in string using regex

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have a string, different version of the input string:

```
a) Name='book' Number='345' Version='12' Author='name1'
b) Name='book' Version='12' Author='name1' Number='345'
```

I need to remove `Version='xx' and Number='xx'`from this input string. Values of this parameters can be always changed.

What is the best way to do it? I tried regex, something like:

```
String input = input.substring(0, input.indexOf("Number")) + "" + input.substring(input.indexOf("Version"));
```

But that would work only for this case:

```
a) Name='book' Number='345' Version='12' Author='name1'
```

But not for this:

```
b) Name='book' Version='12' Author='name1' Number='345'
```

So how to make a general approach?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression to replace:

```
"Name='book' Number='345' Version='12' Author='name1'"
    .replaceAll("( Number| Version)='\\d+'", "")
```

That returns `Name='book' Author='name1'`

`replaceAll("( Number| Version)='\\d+'", "")` finds `Number` OR `Version` followed by a number in single quotes, and replaces it with a blank string.

As suggested by [Aaron's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/91837424?noredirect=1) below, if the order of key/value pairs can change, then a different regex may be better:

```
s.replaceAll("(?:^| )(?:Number|Version)='\\d+'", "").trim()
```

This will match the keys whether they're preceded by a space or are at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Aren't you missing a group around the `Number| Version` alternation? `Name='book'='345'` doesn't look right to me

Comment: Another problem : since the order of the attributes seems variable, you should match them preceded by either space or the start of the string

Comment: @Aaron Makes perfect sense. I just have to find an explanation for why it works without the group.

Comment: It doesn't, look at what you wrote it returned : `Name='book'='345'` likely isn't what OP wants ;)

Comment: @Aaron 100% Thanks. I'm possibly sleep-typing. You're right

Comment: No problem ! If you missed my previous comment, your regex won't work if the Number or Version attributes come first (since they won't be preceded by a space) ; I'd use `(?:^| )(?:Number|Version)='\\d+'` to solve that

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want to do with regex using replaceAll method as below :

```
    String input = "Name='book' Number='345' Version='12' Author='name1'";
    String input2 = "Name='book' Version='345' Number='12' Author='name1'";

    input = input.replaceAll("(Number|Version)='\\d+'", "");
    input2 = input2.replaceAll("(Number|Version)='\\d+'", "");

    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(input2);
```

output is :

```
Name='book'   Author='name1'
Name='book'   Author='name1'
```